# Batch why <nul breaks my file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, powershell, batch-file

Well guys i am basically trying to get user input and type it on the batch

I will be using backspace and enter so i cant use choice

Thats why i am following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493410/how-to-distinguish-between-enter-and-escape-key-presses-in-interactive-windows-b) To capture characters as ascii

And using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519422/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-create-an-ascii-to-hex-converter-in-batch) to convert the ascii output to characters

The problem here is they both work well when seperated but when on same file they do not work :/

Here is my full batch file

```
@echo off
:: Load the charMacros if not already loaded. The macros are dependent on
:: the active code page, so if it has changed, then the macros are reloaded.
:: The macros are loaded prior to SETLOCAL so that the macros persist after
:: the script terminates
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('chcp') do if "%%A" neq "%#mapCodePage%" (set macrop=tst & goto chr)
:tst
:: Test the Str2Hex macro
set /p "=> Single Key Prompt? " <nul
PowerShell Exit($host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode);
set er=%errorlevel%
set "str=Hello world!"
%@Str2Hex% str hex
%@chr% %er% hw
echo asci=%er% char=%hw%
echo str=%str% hex=%hex%
pause
:chr
<!-- : Begin batch script
@echo off
:: charMacros.bat
::
::   This script installs macros that can be used to interconvert between
::   numeric extended ASCII codes and character values.
::
::   The script defines the following variables:
::
::     @Str2Hex - A macro used to convert a string into a string of hex digit
::                pairs representing the ASCII codes in the string.
::
::     @asc - A macro used to convert a character into the decimal ASCII code
::
::     @ascHex - A macro used to convert a character into the hex ASCII codde
::
::     @chr - A macro used to convert a numeric ASCII code into a character
::
::     #LF - A variable containing a line feed character
::
::     #CR - A variable containing a carriage return character
::
::     #charMap - A variable used by the @asc macro
::
::     #asciiMap - A variable used by the @chr macro
::
::     #mapCodePage - The CHCP setting at the time the maps were loaded
::
::     \n - used for specifiying the end of line in a macro definition
::
:: Originally developed and posted by Dave Benham (with help from DosTips users) at
:: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4284

if "!" == "" >&2 echo ERROR: Delayed expansion must be disabled when loading %~nx0&exit /b 1

:: Define a Carriage Return string, only useable as !#CR!
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "#CR=%%a"

:: Define a Line Feed (newline) string (normally only used as !#LF!)
set #LF=^


:: Above 2 blank lines are required - do not remove

:: Define a newline with line continuation
set ^"\n=^^^%#LF%%#LF%^%#LF%%#LF%^^"

:: Define character maps used to interconvert between extended ASCII codes
:: and characters.
set "#charMap="
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf"') do (
  if defined #charMap (set "#asciiMap=%%A") else set "#charMap= %%A"
)
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('chcp') do set "#mapCodePage=%%A"


:: %@Str2Hex%  StrVar  [RtnVar]
::
::   Converts the string within StrVar into a string of extended ASCII codes,
::   with each code represented as a pair of hexadecimal digits. The length of
::   the result will always be exactly twice the length of the original string.
::
::   Any character within the string that is not in the currently loaded code
::   page will be represented as 00.
::
::   The result is stored in RtnVar, or ECHOed if RtnVar is not specified.
::
::   The macro is safe to "call" regardless whether delayed expansion
::   is enabled or not.
::
::     StrVar = The name of a variable that contains the string
::              to be converted
::
::     RtnVar = The name of the variable used to store the result.
::
set @Str2Hex=for %%# in (1 2) do if %%#==2 (%\n%
for /f "eol= tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%a in ("!#args!") do (endlocal%\n%
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion%\n%
  if defined %%~a (%\n%
    set "str=!%%~a!"%\n%
    set "s=!%%~a!"%\n%
    set "len=0"%\n%
    for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (%\n%
      if "!s:~%%P,1!" neq "" (%\n%
        set /a "len+=%%P"%\n%
        set "s=!s:~%%P!"%\n%
      )%\n%
    )%\n%
    set "rtn="%\n%
    for /l %%N in (0 1 !len!) do (%\n%
      set "chr=!str:~%%N,1!"%\n%
      set "hex="%\n%
      if "!chr!"=="=" set hex=3D%\n%
      if "!chr!"=="^!" set hex=21%\n%
      if "!chr!"=="!#lf!" set hex=0A%\n%
      if not defined hex for /f delims^^=^^ eol^^= %%c in ("!chr!!#CR!") do (%\n%
        set "test=!#asciiMap:*#%%c=!"%\n%
        if not "%%c"=="!test:~0,1!" set "test=!test:*#%%c=!"%\n%
        if "%%c"=="!test:~-0,1!" (set "hex=!test:~1,2!") else set "hex=00"%\n%
      )%\n%
      set "rtn=!rtn!!hex!"%\n%
    )%\n%
    for %%v in (!rtn!) do endlocal^&if "%%~b" neq "" (set "%%~b=%%v") else echo(%%v%\n%
  ) else endlocal%\n%
set "#args=")) else setlocal enableDelayedExpansion^&set #args=,


:: %@asc%  StrVar  Position  [RtnVar]
::
::   Converts a character into the extended ASCII code value.
::   The result is stored in RtnVar, or ECHOed if RtnVar is not specified.
::   A value of -1 is returned if the character is not in the currently loaded
::   code page. The macro is safe to "call" regardless whether delayed expansion
::   is enabled or not.
::
::     StrVar = The name of a variable that contains the character
::              to be converted
::
::     Position = The position of the character within the string
::                to be converted. 0 based.
::
::     RtnVar = The name of the variable used to store the result.
::
set @asc=for %%# in (1 2) do if %%#==2 (%\n%
for /f "eol= tokens=1-3 delims=, " %%a in ("!#args!") do (endlocal%\n%
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion%\n%
  if defined %%~a (%\n%
    set "str=!%%~a!"%\n%
    set /a "n=%%~b" 2^>nul%\n%
    for %%N in (!n!) do set "chr=!str:~%%N,1!"%\n%
    if defined chr (%\n%
      set "rtn="%\n%
      if "!chr!"=="=" set rtn=61%\n%
      if "!chr!"=="^!" set rtn=33%\n%
      if "!chr!"=="!#lf!" set rtn=10%\n%
      if not defined rtn for /f delims^^=^^ eol^^= %%c in ("!chr!!#CR!") do (%\n%
        set "test=!#asciiMap:*#%%c=!"%\n%
        if not "%%c"=="!test:~0,1!" set "test=!test:*#%%c=!"%\n%
        if "%%c"=="!test:~-0,1!" (set /a "rtn=0x!test:~1,2!") else set "rtn=-1"%\n%
      )%\n%
    )%\n%
    for %%v in (!rtn!) do endlocal^&if "%%~c" neq "" (set "%%~c=%%v") else echo(%%v%\n%
  ) else endlocal%\n%
set "#args=")) else setlocal enableDelayedExpansion^&set #args=,


:: %@chr%  AsciiCode  [RtnVar]
::
::   Converts an extended ASCII code into the corresponding character.
::   The result is stored in RtnVar, or ECHOed if RtnVar is not specified.
::   The macro supports value 1 - 255. The value 0 is not supported.
::   The macro is safe to "call" regardless whether delayed expansion is
::   enabled or not.
::
::     AsciiCode - Any value from 1 to 255. The value can be expressed as any
::                 numeric expression supported by SET /A.
::
::     RtnVar - The name of the variable used to store the result
::
set @chr=for %%# in (1 2) do if %%#==2 (%\n%
for /f "eol= tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%a in ("!#args!") do (endlocal%\n%
  setlocal%\n%
  set "NotDelayed=!"%\n%
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion%\n%
  set "n=0"%\n%
  set /a "n=%%~a"%\n%
  if !n! gtr 255 set "n=0"%\n%
  if !n! gtr 0 (%\n%
    if !n! equ 10 (%\n%
      for %%C in ("!#LF!") do (%\n%
        endlocal^&endlocal%\n%
        if "%%~b" neq "" (set "%%~b=%%~C") else echo(%%~C%\n%
      )%\n%
    ) else (%\n%
      for %%N in (!n!) do set "c=!#charMap:~%%N,1!"%\n%
      if "!c!" equ "^!" if not defined NotDelayed set "c=^^^!"%\n%
      for /f delims^^=^^ eol^^= %%C in ("!c!!#CR!") do (%\n%
        endlocal^&endlocal%\n%
        if "%%~b" neq "" (set "%%~b=%%C") else echo(%%C%\n%
      )%\n%
    )%\n%
  ) else endlocal^&endlocal%\n%
set "#args=")) else setlocal enableDelayedExpansion^&set #args=,


:: %@ascHex%  StrVar  Position  [RtnVar]
::
::   Converts a character into the extended ASCII code hex value.
::   The result is stored in RtnVar, or ECHOed if RtnVar is not specified.
::   A value of -1 is returned if the character is not in the currently loaded
::   code page. The macro is safe to "call" regardless whether delayed expansion
::   is enabled or not.
::
::     StrVar = The name of a variable that contains the character
::              to be converted
::
::     Position = The position of the character within the string
::                to be converted. 0 based.
::
::     RtnVar = The name of the variable used to store the result.
::
set @ascHex=for %%# in (1 2) do if %%#==2 (%\n%
for /f "eol= tokens=1-3 delims=, " %%a in ("!#args!") do (endlocal%\n%
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion%\n%
  if defined %%~a (%\n%
    set "str=!%%~a!"%\n%
    set /a "n=%%~b" 2^>nul%\n%
    for %%N in (!n!) do set "chr=!str:~%%N,1!"%\n%
    if defined chr (%\n%
      set "rtn="%\n%
      if "!chr!"=="=" set rtn=3D%\n%
      if "!chr!"=="^!" set rtn=21%\n%
      if "!chr!"=="!#lf!" set rtn=0A%\n%
      if not defined rtn for /f delims^^=^^ eol^^= %%c in ("!chr!!#CR!") do (%\n%
        set "test=!#asciiMap:*#%%c=!"%\n%
        if not "%%c"=="!test:~0,1!" set "test=!test:*#%%c=!"%\n%
        if "%%c"=="!test:~-0,1!" (set "rtn=!test:~1,2!") else set "rtn=-1"%\n%
      )%\n%
    )%\n%
    for %%v in (!rtn!) do endlocal^&if "%%~c" neq "" (set "%%~c=%%v") else echo(%%v%\n%
  ) else endlocal%\n%
set "#args=")) else setlocal enableDelayedExpansion^&set #args=,

cls
goto %macrop%


----- Begin wsf script --->
<job><script language="VBScript">
for i=1 to 255
  if i=10 then WScript.Stdout.Write " " else WScript.Stdout.Write chr(i)
next
WScript.Stdout.Write chr(10)+"#"
for i=1 to 255
  if i<>10 then WScript.Stdout.Write chr(i)+chr(i)+right("0"+hex(i),2)+"#"
next
</script></job>
```

in line 6 If i change goto chr to call charmacros.bat it works

in line 9 if i remove the `<nul` it works but since it needs you to press enter it will detect enter only

So where does the code breaks ? / Why does `<nul` breaks the ascii to char ?

Answer (score 1):

The original charMacros.bat script is a hybrid batch/WSF(VBS) script that was intended to be a stand-alone script.

You certainly can combine it with other code, but you must follow the rules for a hybrid batch/WSF script.

The redirection in your code is confusing the WSF parser.

The following line should be moved to the top and the problem will be solved:

```
<!-- : Begin batch script
```

You should read [Liviu's original description of the batch/WSF hybrid technique](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=33963#p33963) and/or read my batch/WSF solution to [Is it possible to embed and execute VBScript within a batch file without using a temporary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9074476/1012053)